# run tests after server restarted after code changed

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have [grunt-nodeunit](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-nodeunit) task with watcher and [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon). So when I do any changes to files **grunt-nodeunit** and **nodemon** starts working simultaneously. While **grunt-nodeunit** executes tests **nodemon** restarts server. So I got some fake failed tests. How to run tests after server restarts?

My grunt config:

```
 grunt.initConfig({
    nodeunit: {
        all: ['./test.nodeunit/**/*.coffee']

    },
    watch: {
       all: {
            files: ['**/*.coffee', '**/*.jade'],
            tasks: ['nodeunit']
        }
    }
});
```

My nodemon configured in `package.json`:

```
"start": "nodemon app.js"
```

Comment: Your tests require that your product be running?  That's odd to me.  To run the product, that means you successfully built it.  If you successfully built it, shouldn't your tests have already passed?

Comment: I'm checking status code, title and description of site pages via http requests. So it require my product to be running.

Comment: then fake (mock) the your http_request (or the result of it)